# Checking if a string parameter contains only digits

Tags: java, beginner

```
 public void setMobile(String mobile) {
      char[] mobileList = mobile.toCharArray();
      boolean isValid = true;
      for(char x : mobileList)
      {
          if(!Character.isDigit(x))
          {
              isValid = false;
          }
      }
      if(isValid)
      {
          this.mobile = mobile;
      }
    }
```

Is this the best way of doing things? Cheers.

Comment: When entering a phone number, punctuation like spaces, dashes and parentheses should be allowed, as well as a leading plus. Refer to the ITU E.123 recommendation. When displaying the phone number, a canonical format can be used.

Answer (score 15):

There is one major flaw that will come back and haunt you with this code. If you enter an *invalid* number, there is absolutely no indication whatsoever that it was invalid.

If it is **not** valid, you should do this:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid mobile number: " + mobile);
```

Incorporating Heslacher's suggestions I would do this:

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    if (!containsOnlyDigits(mobile)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid mobile number: " + mobile);
    }
    this.mobile = mobile;
}
```

Another edge case that should be handled is the empty string. I *assume* you don't want to classify that as a valid mobile number? Then handle it also in `containsOnlyDigits` or handle it in `setMobile`.

```
if (mobile.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty string is not a valid mobile number");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should extract the validation, meaning the checking if the string only contains digits, to a separate method like so

```
private static boolean containsOnlyDigits(final String value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        if(!Character.isDigit(value.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and use it in the `setMobile()` method like so

```
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    if(containsOnlyDigits(mobile)) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

So each method is doing only one thing.

Because the method `setMobile()` is `public` you should check if the passed `mobile` is not `null`.

Disclaimer: Written in the editor without testing.

Comment: Java 8: `return value.chars().allMatch(i -> Character.isDigit((char) i));` Note that `CharacterSequence.chars` [returns an `IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--)

Comment: @SimonForsberg You could use `Character::isDigit`. There is an overload for code points (`int`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex `^\d{1,10}$` to check this as below example:

```
private static final String regex="^\\d{1,10}$";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("123456".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("123abc".matches(regex));
}
```

Where regex means:

- `^` -> starts of string
- `\d` -> only digits
- `{1, 10}` -> min 1 digit, max 10 digits
- `$` -> end of string

So, complete regex -> input string starts with digit, should be minimum 1 digit, max 10 digits, and also ends with digit. And no other characters allowed in between.

Comment: note that \d != [0-9]. \d also includes Persian, Hebrew and other non-latin digits. Which is also true for Character.isDigit().

Comment: The original code did not have any length requirements on the string. What if you have a number with 11 digits?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid `\d' checks only for decimal digits and so does Character.isDigit().

For th eregex you can see http://fiddle.re/04kuvn and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Owh wait, you mean it only matches latin digits? That is an odd implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Since, we're discussing Java, I am surprised no one mentioned using `Integer.parseInt(mobile`) and surround it with a try-catch block; where, the occurrence of the `NumberFormatException` would indicate that the `String` mobile doesn't just contain digits. If the exception didn't occur, you'd have also converted the `String` to `Integer`.